# Do you generate your data dictionary?

Tags: sql-server, code-generation, data-dictionary

Do you generate your data dictionary? If so, how?

I use extended procedures in SQL Server 2005 to hold onto table and field information. I have some queries that create a dictionary out of them, but it's ... meh.  Do you have a particular query or tool you use? Do you generate it off of your database diagrams?

Googling for "data dictionary sql server" comes up with many queries, but they're all about equally as attractive. Which is to say, good starting off points, but not production ready.

Comment: you can generate data dictionary by using simple sql statements. you can find exapmle here http://csharpalley.com/create-sql-server-data-dictionary-using-extended-properties/

Comment: You can search for a tool here: http://tools.dataedo.com. Quite a big list of data dictionary tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) is a really nice tool that can reverse engineer a description of a database. This includes:

- ERD
- List of tables, columns, and constraints
- Set of warnings about DB anomalied (e.g. tables without indexes)

Comment: I, too, used to have a BBC ;-}

Answer (score 6):

Recently I had a task to document a fairly large database (around 500 objects) and details I found here really helped.

Here is some feedback on how we implemented this – hopefully someone will find it useful even though it’s quite late.

**Technique:**

- Extended properties in all objects + [third party tool](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.aspx) to generate docs

**What was documented:**

- All tables and some columns (we added good descriptions for all tables to really make sure it’s clear what the table is about)
- All views – descriptions on why the view was created, what tables are included in the data and such and also when to use
- All stored procedures – while going through the process we found that we had a lot of duplicate stored procedures ( devs didn’t bother to see if proc exists so they created new ones )
- All UDFs and some other objects as well but not all (we didn’t really have the need to document triggers)

What we ended up doing is having our DBA to reject all DDL updates that come from devs unless there are extended properties.

We also have a scheduled task to automatically re-create documentation every 2 weeks.

Answer (score 5):

We use extended properties.

To read them, we use [sys.extended_properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186989(SQL.90).aspx)
It makes things a lot easier.

We also use Red Gate SQL Doc

Answer (score 2):

I use this tool (open source): http://www.codeplex.com/datadictionary.
All the information I create gets added in the Extended Properties of the database.

Answer (score 1):

I generate it from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views plus other tables of metadata which are application specific.

I also use wildcard searches of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` in order to track usage patterns within code and identify unused columns and tables.

This article just showed up in one of my news feeds: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1619

Answer (score 0):

We generate the database's dictionnary on the developper's side of the application. We have a nice procedure using an ADODB connection + ADOX objects and collections. This procedure will browse all tables in the database. The following main data is collected:

1. TableName
2. ColumnName
3. ColumnType
4. ColumnSize
5. bool_ColumnIsThePrimaryKey
6. bool_ColumnHasReferentialIntegrityConstraint

You can also follow up field default values, etc.

It is then possible for example to :

- check in how many tables my field
  `currency_id` (primary key of the
  `Tbl_currency` table)is referenced,
  and if referential integrity is each
  time properly implemented (we very
  often create the field without
  implementing the corresponding rules
  ...).
- Make sure that fields of similar
  logical type (like "`description`"
  fields) are of similar data
  type/size. Nothing is so frustrating
  that having a `item_Description nvarchar(50)` field in a table, and a
  `document_Description ntext` in another
  table!
- etc.

All the data extracted through the procedure is inserted in a local table (could be an XML file or whatever) and saved for further use.

A column dictionnary/report can be generated from this data through

```
SELECT DISTINT columnName FROM Tbl_Column
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to create the Data Dictionary while the database is being designed. Of course, this isn't always an option...

I think the answer depends on the current state of the database? Is it done and in production? Have you yet to start on it? (etc.)

In the past, like Cade Roux, I've pulled the information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA in to an access database. Currently we have developers occasionally adding information about the different tables, columns, stored procedures, functions, etc. to the Access database. Inside the Access database, we've created reports to output a neat looking "Data Dictionary" print out.

It is not the most efficient way to accomplish creating a data dictionary but given that the project had gone 3 years without any sign of a data dictionary, this is what we had to do.

So ultimately, the answer to this depends on your database's state.

Best Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

We wrote our own Data dictionary utility that used extended properties, but when we found Redgate's tool, we abandoned it for their tool.  Worked great for us!  I guess it helped that we already had field and table descriptions out there in extended properties.  Not to advertise for a company, but they have a 14day free trial.  It's worth a look.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with [SQL Data Dictionary](http://www.sqldatadictionary.com/).