# What are some options for implementing search on a ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, seo

I am currently finishing up my first ASP.NET MVC application and would like to implement site searching.  What are some options for allowing a visitor to search the site?

Comment: I asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390106/how-do-i-build-a-search-mechanism-for-my-application) similar question sometime back. Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 2):

[Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Answers to the following questions may help...

1. Is most/all content public, or login-protected?  (i.e. can Google index it?)  Or, would a "search appliance" be an alternative (though $$)?
2. If you want to use full-text search, how many different tables/columns need to be searched?  What would your queries look like, if using LINQ?  :)
3. Are common search terms represented in the page URLs?  If doing custom searching, can you also search these, possibly with higher weight than in-page content?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/). Its free and works of intranet apps.